# objective c NSURL may not respond to +initFileURLWithPath

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have two lines of code in the applicationDidFinishLaunching function:

```
NSString *targetFilePath = @"/Users/bob/Documents/About_Stacks.pdf";
NSURL *targetFileURL = [NSURL initFileURLWithPath:targetFilePath];
```

and I am getting the warning (title) in the second line...

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. This is an absurdly simply application... I have read other posts about reordering methods, but I am using classes provided by NS, nothing of my own.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`initFileURLWithPath:` is an instance method, not a class method, so you have to create an instance of the class first with `alloc`. So:

```
NSString* targetFilePath = @"/Users/bob/Documents/About_Stacks.pdf";
NSURL* targetFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:targetFilePath];
```

If you want to use the convenience method, use `fileURLWithPath:`, so:

```
NSURL* targetFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:targetFilePath];
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to `alloc` an `NSURL` first.

```
NSURL *targetFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:targetFilePath];
```

If the method starts with "init", it means it should be called on an allocated instance, not on the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is normal as the method `initFileURLWithPath` is an instance method and not a class method. The proper way to use it is:

```
NSString *targetFilePath = @"/Users/bob/Documents/About_Stacks.pdf";
NSURL *targetFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:targetFilePath];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the NSURL has to created first using alloc .
Just declaring it will not work.

Also I think you will need to release it later, otherwise there will be a potential leak.

```
 NSURL *targetFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:targetFilePath];
```

//do some stuff

```
[targetFileURL release ];
```